# React: Clicking an interactive element inside a disabled button - Chrome doesnt fire but Safari does

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

In my react application, I have a disabled button, and inside of that button, I have an element that I wish to click. This is due to it being a Tooltip, and the tooltip content being rendered displayed INSIDE the button. Due to circumstances, I would like to avoid moving the tooltip out.

For simplicity, I've recreated the scenario, with a clickable element inside a disabled button. On click of the inner element, a log should happen to the console.

[image]

```
<button type="button" disabled onClick={() => console.log('outer')}>
  dont click me
  <div 
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'cyan' }} 
    onClick={() => console.log('inner')}
  >
    but click me
  </div>
</button>
```

On Chrome, when I click "but click me", nothing fires. On Safari, however, the click event DOES fire. Curiously, someone had an outdated version of Chrome, and that also fired the click handler, so this is a change in the Chrome browser in the last few months I imagine.

Are there any attributes I can set to enable Safari's behaviour in Chrome? I tried `pointer-events` and other Googled solutions, but most of them refer to event propagation where the inner child is disabled, whereas my scenario is the other way around.

My last resort is to remove the disabled attribute from the underlying DOM element and just style it as disabled, but I'd like to avoid that if possible for accessibility reasons (I appreciate the irony of requiring accessibility in an element that is awful for accessibility).

Comment: `div` is not a valid child of `button`. Chrome's behavior seems correct. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: I understand my markup is incorrect and that the real solution is to properly format the tooltip to be outside of the button, using a portal, or wire in an anchor element, to not have an interactive element inside an interactive element. We're using a dropdown list library, and have very little control or ability to do that however, and while I understand its incorrect, was hoping we could at least fall back on Safari's behaviour so, while semantically being wrong, the functionality at least still works

Comment: Is the dropdown library open-source? Maybe we can find a way to get it to work for you without changing it

Comment: It's an internal library managed by another team. I did pull the source, modified it to allow wrappers and moved the tooltip outside the button, but it caused some real problems with positioning. Hence why I was hoping there was an easy fix with pointer-events or something. Maybe I'm outta luck!